# Should 'strict-mode', 'use-strict' and 'strict' tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [strict-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict-mode), [use-strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-strict) and [strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict) tags be merged?

I think so because they refer to the same action: activating strict mode. What do you think?

Comment: There's also `strict`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Thanks for your comment, Matthew. I updated my question.

Comment: And even [tag:strictmode], which apparently is for Android though the tag only differs by a hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

[strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict) is the more used tag, and the minimalist in me says that it is the one that should survive.

However, it should have a tag wiki first.  I know about the perl meaning, but it also seems to be appropriate to javascript and possibly android, php and a few others, based on use of the tag.  Plus some uses about "scrict" keeping to various standards.

I suggest waiting for the tag wiki entry that you have suggested to be approved or improved, which is likely.  That also gives time for this MSO question to get more exposure, to see if anyone objects.  No downvotes as of yet implies that nobody does object.  Then, say in a day or two, suggest edits for the 60 questions under the `strict-mode` and `use-strict` tags and retag them as simply `strict` and see if they get accepted.  Leaving a good comment on the retag will improve the chances of their being accepted.

Once the tags have no questions, they will go away on their own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just added the tag wiki for strict.

Comment: @pablofiumara The proposed wiki text is not sufficient.  It covers javascript only.

Comment: You are right. I have just updated the tag strict wiki using a more general description.